# Lua, if statement idiom

Tags: lua

```
local a = {}
local b = {}

local c,d = (a~=nil) and 1,1 or 0,0 -- prints "1 1"

local c,d = (a==nil) and 1,1 or 0,0 -- prints "false 1"

print(c,d)
```

I get why this happens. Is there a way to print "0 0"?

Comment: use an if statement?

Comment: @Mooing Duck, I hate "if statements", they are big and ugly.

Comment: They also prevent silly mistakes like you have in your code. Would you rather have compressed code, or code that actually works?

Comment: `print("0 0")` will print 0 0. Alternatively, `print("\"0 0\"")` will print "0 0".

Comment: I see that you've found an answer. So, you should see in your question, the last two assignment statements assign the first two of three values to two variables and discards the last value; `,0` isn't doing anything.

Comment: `local c, d = unpack((a~=nil) and {1,1} or {0,0})`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff, Beautiful!Love it!Good job!

Comment: @Mooing Duck from my experience, they also perform faster.

Comment: @user6245072: It isn't faster. [Lua has no ternary bytecode](http://wiki.luajit.org/Optimizations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to print "0 0"?

No, because `and or` expression always returns one result and the results you see are probably not for the reason you think they are.

> local c,d = (a~=nil) and 1,1 or 0,0 -- prints "1 1"

This is calculated as `((a~=nil) and 1),(1 or 0),0`. The first expression returns 1, the second (`1 or 0`) returns 1 and the last one is ignored (as you have two variables on the left side and three expressions on the right).

> local c,d = (a==nil) and 1,1 or 0,0 -- prints "false 1"

This is calculated in a similar way, except `(a==nil)` is `false` and that's why you get the second result.

To do what you want, you'll need to split it into two expressions: one for `c` and one for `d`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this in the most compact way possible, you can create a function to do it. I generally only have it take one parameter per condition, but if you absolutely need one that handles multiples, there are two ways to do it.

Option #1: Take tables:

```
function iff(cond, tbl1, tbl2)
  if(cond) then
    return unpack(tbl1)
  else
    return unpack(tbl2)
  end
end
```

Obviously, this requires that you always pass tables. If you only need single values, then you'd need a second version of the function. That's preferable to adding conditional logic based on types, thus slowing your code down.

Option #2: Variadic:

```
--Number of parameters ought to be even.
--The first half are returned if the condition is true,
--the second half if it is false.
function iff(cond, ...)
  if(cond) then
    return ... --Yes, you're returning all of them, but the user shouldn't be trying to take more than the first half.
  else
    return select((select("#", ...)) / 2, ...)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by "Paul Kulchenko" in his last sentence, I ended up adding two idioms...

```
local a = {}
local b = {}

local c,d = (a~=nil) and 1 or 0, (a~=nil) and 1 or 0 -- prints "1 1"

local c,d = (a==nil) and 1 or 0, (a==nil) and 1 or 0 -- prints "0 0"

print(c,d)
```